# Автоматический запуск pm2 (Discord Bot)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, discord, cron, crontab

У меня есть Discord бот и я хочу, чтобы он автоматически запускался, в случае перезагрузки сервера

Бот запускается при помощи команды:

```
pm2 start index.js
```

Вывод будет примерно следующий:
[image: Старт бота]

При попытке запустить бота снова я получу ошибку, естественно потому что, он уже запущен:
[image: Повторная попытка старта]

Перезапускается бот командой:

```
pm2 restart index.js
```

Для предотвращения самоотключения бота я использую:

```
 pm2 restart index.js --cron "30 */12 * * *"
```

Статистика показала, что перезапускать его два раза в день - достаточно

Но я хочу, чтобы в случае перезагрузки сервера бот запустился, соответственно параметр `--cron` мне не подходит
Попытка создать запись в `crontab` ничего не дала (бот не запустился, лог создался, но в него ничего не записалось)

```
*/2 * * * * cd /root/discord-bot/ && pm2 start index.js > /root/cronlog.log
```

*(Старт бота каждые две минуты, ведь если он уже запущен, то он не запустится, получается такая проверка на то, запущен ли бот)*

`>/dev/null 2>&1` тоже не дал результатов

```
*/2 * * * * cd /root/discord-bot/ && pm2 start index.js >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Как мне заставить бота проверяться на запуск и запускаться автоматически, даже если сервер был перезагружен?**

Comment: Варианта так-то два... 1. Исправить бота что-бы его не надо было рестартовать. 2. Позволить PM2 делать свою работу и не изобретать велосипед с квадратными колесами.

Comment: Очень глупый комментарий. Как я должен исправить бота, если электричество на сервере вырубится и его придётся вручную перезагрузить? 

Моя задача - автоматически запускать бота после перезагрузки сервера
`--cron` с pm2 работают просто замечательно и к ним никаких претензий